# How to get the transaction payment amount in .NET Stellar API?

Tags: stellar-sdk, c#-sdk, dotnet-sdk

I have C# source code like this:

```
 Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");
 var GetTranHistory = server.Operations.ForAccount("GDLRM2QFV7GOOAZDELHFCC5RBRMX4NAZNBSTAKG6NGO4CFODY5PSCYWT").Stream(EventHandler<OperationResponse> Listener);
```

Question: How to build the `Listener` function to fetch all transaction payments returned from the Stellar API, so I can get the transaction history amount for each?

[This page](https://elucidsoft.github.io/) does not show an example how to build it. The C# SDK has less support.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found ald. Should call stream listener func to get data result from list of operation then find it via your wish accountID
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C#, but I think you should get [this value](https://github.com/elucidsoft/dotnet-stellar-sdk/blob/7e19bed2d3217ca4b436d4eb6fa35f028e69be0b/stellar-dotnet-sdk/responses/operations/PaymentOperationResponse.cs#L44) from the response, hope this helps.